# D3.js not aligning column values along y axis accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, d3.js

Brand new to D3.js and **damn** what a learning curve....

Below is the graph as it stand when my page is loaded with the original static data. As you can see from the picture, the columns rise sequentially from left to right as they should.

[image]

I have the D3 code placed inside a Backbone view. The goal of this program is to change the values on a set interval. When the values change I want to use the `transform` aspect of D3 to animate the column moving either up or down depending on the number.

However, I'd like them to all move up and down based on a set y axis that applies to each column. It seems, instead, that each column moves the numbers up and down based upon a different y axis, and this changes in each column with each iteration. For example, a column with a value of 115311 could wind up moving down if a value of 188000 is generated, then up again for a value of 112000.

For example, here are the columns after the second iteration of numbers are created (also note, the `rect` elements that serve as the columns are not being re-drawn. If anyone has any idea why that is happening as well it would be greatly appreciated)

[image]

**Model**

```
var DataPoint = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function (lbl, ctrct, rtrn) {
        this.set({
            label: lbl,
            contract: ctrct,
            annReturn: rtrn
        })
    },

    randomize: function () {
        this.set({
            contract: (Math.random() * (140000 - 100000 + 1) + 100000).toFixed(2)
        });
    }
});
```

**Collection**

```
var DataSeries = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: DataPoint,

    fetch: function () {
        this.reset();
        this.add([
            new DataPoint("1/7yrs", "111830.17", "1.63%"),
            new DataPoint("2/7yrs", "115311.17", "2.07%"),
            new DataPoint("3/7yrs", "118984.65", "2.52%"),
            new DataPoint("4/7yrs", "122859.65", "2.98%"),
            new DataPoint("5/7yrs", "126947.77", "3.46%"),
            new DataPoint("6/7yrs", "131260.74", "3.94%"),
            new DataPoint("7/7yrs", "135810.92", "4.44%")
        ])
    },

    randomize: function () {
        this.each(function (m) {
            m.randomize();
        });
    }
});
```

**View**

```
var BarGraph = Backbone.View.extend({

    "el": "#graph",

    options: {barDemo: ""},

    initialize: function (options) {

        _.bindAll(this, "render", "frame");
        this.collection.bind("change", this.render);
        this.options.barDemo = d3.selectAll($(this.el)).append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height + 60);
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    render: function () {
        var data = this.collection.models;
        var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            console.log(d);
            console.log();
             return d.attributes.contract
        })])
            .rangeRound([0, height]);

        this.options.barDemo.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                //console.log(x(i));
                 return x(i);
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                //console.log(height - y(d.attributes.contract));
                return height - y(d.attributes.contract);
            })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
                console.log(y(d.attributes.contract));
                return y(d.attributes.contract);
            })
            .attr("width", barWidth)
            .attr("fill", "#2d578b");

        this.options.barDemo.selectAll("text")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                //console.log(x(i) + barWidth);
                 return x(i) + barWidth;
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return height - y(d.attributes.contract);
            })
            .attr("dx", -barWidth / 2)
            .attr("dy", "1.2em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) {
                //console.log(d.contract);
                return d.attributes.contract
            })
            .attr("fill", "white");

        this.options.barDemo.selectAll("text.yAxis")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(i) + barWidth; })
            .attr("y", height)
            .attr("dx", -barWidth / 2)
            .attr("dy", "15px")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family; Helvetica, sans-serif")
            .text(function (d) { return d.label; })
            .attr("transform", "translate(0, 18)")
            .attr("class", "yAxis");

        var rect = this.options.barDemo.selectAll("rect").data(data, function (d, i) { return i; });

        rect.enter().insert("rect", "text").attr("x", function (d, i) {
            return x(i);
        }).attr("height", function (d) {
            return x(d.attributes.contract);
        }).attr("width", barWidth);

        rect.transition().duration(1000).attr("height", function (d) {
            return x(d.attributes.contract);
        }).attr("width", barWidth);

        rect.exit().remove();

        var text = this.options.barDemo.selectAll("text").data(data, function (d, i) {
            return i;
        });

        text.enter().append("text")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(i) + barWidth; })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return height - y(d.attributes.contract); })
            .attr("dx", -barWidth / 2)
            .attr("dy", "1.2em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function (d) { return d.attributes.contract })
            .attr("fill", "white");

        text
        .transition()
        .duration(1100)
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.attributes.contract);
        })
         .text(function (d) { return d.attributes.contract; });

    },

    frame: function () {
        //this.chart.append("line").attr("y1", 0).attr("y2", h - 10).style("stroke", "#000");

        //this.chart.append("line").attr("x1", 0).attr("x2", w).attr("y1", h - 10).attr("y2", h - 10).style("stroke", "#000");
    }
});
```

**Startup code**

```
$(function() {
    var dataSeries = new DataSeries();
    new BarGraph({
        collection: dataSeries
    }).render();

    setInterval(function () {
        dataSeries.randomize();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: fyi the second column # is higher than the first.

Comment: this question is very basic d3 how to make a chart. i recommend the relevant tutorial: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/ look at three little circles for update patterns.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I noticed that I'm only using `.linear()` when it appears I should be using `.ordinal()` for my `y axis`, however it seems like I'm using a different method than the one in the tutorial.

Comment: You need to update the data. The linear vs. ordinal scales are not the issue. It's the basics of the design implementation. Look for anything focused on enter. update exit patterns. http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Comment: I see two/three areas where I use enter. Is there a specific portion of the code you're referencing? I'm 2/3 days new to D3 so as much info as you got I'd appreciate greatly :)

Comment: I'm referring to the entire design. You won't use transform. You'll use an update pattern, which is where you need to start in fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that finally fixed my `render` function. I needed to adjust the `y` and `height`  attributes in when the `rect` was changed and selected, mainly, among a couple other minor changes.

```
render: function () {
        var data = this.collection.models;
        var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([100000, 140000]).range([height, 0]);

        this.options.barDemo.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(i); })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.attributes.contract); })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.attributes.contract); })
            .attr("width", barWidth)
            .attr("fill", "#2d578b");

        this.options.barDemo.selectAll("text")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(i) + barWidth; })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.attributes.contract); })
            .attr("dx", -barWidth / 2)
            .attr("dy", "1.2em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) { return d.attributes.contract; })
            .attr("fill", "white");

        this.options.barDemo.selectAll("text.yAxis")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("svg:text")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x(i) + barWidth; })
            .attr("y", height)
            .attr("dx", -barWidth / 2)
            .attr("dy", "15px")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family; Helvetica, sans-serif")
            .text(function (d) { return d.attributes.label; })
            .attr("transform", "translate(0, 18)")
            .attr("class", "yAxis");

        var rect = this.options.barDemo.selectAll("rect").data(data, function (d, i) { return i; });

        rect.enter().append("rect", "text").attr("x", function (d, i) {
            return x(i);
        }).attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.attributes.contract);
        }).attr("height", function (d) {
            return height - y(d.attributes.contract);
        }).attr("width", barWidth);

        rect.transition().duration(1000).attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.attributes.contract);
        }).attr("height", function (d) {
            return height - y(d.attributes.contract);
        }).attr("width", barWidth);

        rect.exit().remove();

        var text = this.options.barDemo.selectAll("text").data(data, function (d, i) {
            return i;
        });

        text
        .transition()
        .duration(1100)
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.attributes.contract);
        })
         .text(function (d) {
             console.log("from transition");
             console.log(d);
              return d.attributes.contract;
         });
    },
```